# Rebuilding e.namedValues in Index Order, Pushing to Document in Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have a Google Form that has many different branches; as a result, out of ~100 questions in total, any given response only includes about 20 answers. I'm trying to find a way to remove questions and answers to which the answer is "" (blank) and then push the questions and answers to a Google Document.

I'm using e.namedValues triggered on FormSubmit. But, of course, e.namedValues doesn't actually return the responses in the order that the questions were asked. I need a way to:

1. Build an array of questions and answers where only those questions and answers are shown where the answer has a response
2. Sort that array so that the questions and answers are in the order that they were asked
3. Push that array into a Google Document (ideally, a table, but I'm unable to do that with the arrays that I'm building).

Here's my current code:

```
function formResponsetoGoogleDoc(e) {
  var formID = {{ Insert FormID Here }};
  var response = e.namedValues;
  var document = DocumentApp.create('Test').getBody();
  var questions = FormApp.openById(formID).getItems();
  var questionarray = [];
  for (Key in response) {
    var label = Key;
    var data = response[Key];
    if (data != "") {
      for (q in questions) {
        var title = questions[q].getTitle();
        if (title == label) {
          var number = questions[q].getIndex();
        }
      }
      questionarray.push(number + " - " + label + ": " + data);
      document.appendListItem(number + " - " + label + ": " + data)
    }
  }
  questionarray.sort();
  Logger.log(questionarray);
}
```

This code doesn't work. Currently, questionarray gets sorted in the order of questions (e.g.) 0, 0, 15, 16, 17, 18, 18, 19, 2, 20, 21, 23, 24). Also, any time I try to use this as an appendtable, I get "Exception: The parameters (number[]) don't match the method signature for DocumentApp.Body.appendTable."

Would really appreciate any help that you can give. Willing to consider using e.values as well, but I've never figured out how to cull both questions and (non-)answers from the two arrays needed. I have too many questions to justify hardcoding the replacetext options either, so I'm trying to avoid that.

Comment: From my limited experience with Google Forms e.values is in the same order as the form.

Comment: Also I believe that the names for the named values come from the header line in the response sheet. So if you want to access the named values in the same order as the form you could iterate through the header array to access the named values data in the same order. If that's what your after, I'm not really sure. –

Comment: Could you link it to a spreadsheet so that the responses are automatically posted in question-asking order, and then extract them from the sheet into a document or table from there? Would this be a viable solution?

Comment: as @Rafa Guillermo said work from a spreadsheet. Response from Google forms can be sent to a spreadsheet and you can pull data from spreadsheets as arrays and do all kinds of filtering.

Comment: @Cooper You're right, e.values follows the same order as the form, so I can get it and a 1-D array of the headings, but then I need a way to somehow remove the empty e.values from the array but also store the index numbers of those removals so that I can remove those indexes from the heading array. Honestly, I'm lost as to how to do just that.

Comment: @RafaGuillermo: I'd like to automate it. To do that, you must mean that I should do a for loop, i.e. (in plain language) for each column in the newest response, if the response is not empty grab the relevant header row of the spreadsheet and then the response, correct?

The solution to this is in how to set up that for loop I think, if I'm understanding you right.

Comment: @aNewb I couldn't tag both you and RafaGuillermo so I had to just respond to him, but I think I understand what you're saying - can you check my comment? How would I go about implementing your solution?

Comment: The order is the same order that the headers in the sheet are and in fact the headers are the names that are in the namedValues so they are the e.namedValues key in the order of the question.  What more do you need?

Answer (score 2):

#### Answer:

*You can use filter to remove empty responses while storing the index of the empty value.*

#### Code Example:

Let `e.values` be:

```
e.values = ["Response 0", "Response 1", "", "Response 3", "Response 4", "", "", "", "Response 9"];
```

We can filter out the empty responses and use another array to store the indices which were removed:

```
function filterValues(e) {
  var indices = [];
  var filtered = e.values.filter(function (response, i) {
    if (response == "") indices.push(i);
    return response != "";
  });
  
  console.log(filtered);
  console.log(indices);
}
```

Will display the following in the console:

```
Jan 11, 2021, 10:50:33 PM   Debug   [ 'Response 0',
  'Response 1',
  'Response 3',
  'Response 4',
  'Response 8' ]
Jan 11, 2021, 10:50:33 PM   Debug   [ 2, 5, 6, 7 ]
```

#### References:

- [Array.prototype.filter() - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to battle with this problem a while longer because you don't seem to be able to articulate a very specific question.  But you seem to have interest in determining which answers have been answered and in what order and also you seem to want the the index of the answers that don't.  I believe this data set should provide you some insight as to how you can obtain that information.  The information for each form submission is appended to a spreadsheet along with the headers.

```
function onMySubmit(e) {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const osh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  let arr1=[['Header','Value','Index','Column']];
  let sh=e.range.getSheet();
  let hA=sh.getRange(1,1,1,sh.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
  let col={};
  let hdr={};
  hA.forEach((h,i)=>{col[i]=i+1;hdr[i]=h;});
  e.values.map((v,i)=>{arr1.push([hdr[i],v,i,col[i]]);});
  osh.getRange(osh.getLastRow()+1,1,arr1.length,arr1[0].length).setValues(arr1);  
}
```

Comment: ```e.values``` doesn't come with "headers" and it comes as an array - not an object, right? How do answer values get "organized" as per columns' indexes (```hA```)? ```sh``` is declared twice... Thanks!

Comment: Where are two sh declarations.  There is one on line 3.  I see no others.  Headers are from row one of the sheet and e.values follows the same sequential order as the columns in the linked sheett.

Comment: Yeah.  I meant one of them to be the output sheet.